# Python: How to replace string elements using an array of tuples?

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace the characters of the reversed alphabet with those of the alphabet. This is what I've got:

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
rev_alphabet = alphabet[::-1]

sample = "wrw blf hvv ozhg mrtsg'h vkrhlwv?"

def f(alph, rev_alph):
    return (alph, rev_alph)

char_list_of_tups = list(map(f, alphabet, rev_alphabet))

for alph, rev_alph in char_list_of_tups:
    sample = sample.replace(rev_alph, alph)

print(sample)
```

expected output: did you see last night's episode?

actual output: wrw you svv ozst nrtst's vprsowv?

I understand that I'm printing the last "replacement" of the whole iteration. How can I avoid this without appending it to a list and then running into problems with the spacing of the words?

Comment: Let's say your string is "ww" in 1st iteration the string would be "dd" in 2nd iteration "dd"  would become "ww".

Comment: One option is to use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to do the translation in one pass and avoid the issue you are describing.

Comment: Side-note: `list(map(f, alphabet, rev_alphabet))` is a slow (and verbose since you have to define `f`) way to spell `list(zip(alphabet, rev_alphabet))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem here is that you lose data as you perform each replacement; for a simple example, consider an input of `"az"`. On the first replacement pass, you replace `'z'` with `'a'`, and now have `"aa"`. When you get to replacing `'a'` with `'z'`, it becomes `"zz"`, because you can't tell the difference between an already replaced character and one that's still unchanged.

For single character replacements, you want to use [the `str.translate` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) (and the not strictly required, but useful helper function, [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)), to do character by character transliteration across the string in a single pass.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase  # No need to define the alphabet; Python provides it
                                    # You can use the original str form, no list needed

# Do this once up front, and reuse it for as many translate calls as you like
trans_map = str.maketrans(ascii_lowercase[::-1], ascii_lowercase)

sample = sample.translate(trans_map)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

# or
alphabet = [chr(97 + i) for i in range(0,26)]

sample = "wrw blf hvv ozhg mrtsg'h vkrhlwv?"
res = []
for ch in sample:
    if ch in alphabet:
        res.append(alphabet[-1 - alphabet.index(ch)])
    else:
        res.append(ch)
        
print("".join(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Way if you are ok with creating a new string instead.

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
dictRev = dict(zip(alphabet, alphabet[::-1]))
sample = "wrw blf hvv ozhg mrtsg'h vkrhlwv?"
s1="".join([dictRev.get(char, char) for char in sample])
print(s1)
```

> "did you see last night's episode?"

Comment: They *must* be okay with creating a new string; strings aren't mutable so any "mutation" makes a new one (their old code made 26 new strings). Your code could still reassign the result of the `"".join` back to `sample` and work just fine, the key is that you only performed one replacement per character, you didn't perform 26 such replacements). For all practical purposes, your code is a deoptimized version of `str.translate` (which is, internally, just a loop over the input doing the optimized C-level equivalent of what your `"".join([dictRev.get(char, char) for char in sample])` is doing).